# Does Unhandled exception cause server to be Slow/Sluggish

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp-classic

I have a classic asp, asp.net web application hosted on IIS on windows server 2003, during certain times in the day i see the site is Slow/sluggish. Looking at event viewer I noticed a few Unhandled exceptions in the asp.net application. Could this be the cause of the slowness, if yes why?

Comment: is it classic ASP (files are .asp) or ASP.net (.aspx)?

Comment: The application is basically on classic asp, but have a couple of small applications(sub applications) on asp.net as well. The unhandled exceptions are basically in asp.net application

Comment: Have you checked the logs to see if periods of slowness coincide with bugs in your application(s)?

Comment: yes.. the periods of slowness coincides with the exceptions at times

Comment: Maybe fix the unhandled exceptions and see if the slowness goes away?